# Going back to previous view while pushing data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a list of places with a right navigation bar item linking to a filter page. I want to set paramters on the filter page and push back to the placelist at the push of a button while taking the data with me and refreshing the previous view. I am currently doing this action when the button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    PlaceList *placelist = [[PlaceList alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlaceList" bundle:nil];
    placelist.searchTxt = self.searchTxt.text;
    placelist.type = self.type;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:placelist animated:YES];
    [placelist release]; 
}
```

However this creates a new table in the navigation controller and leaves a back button to the filter eg. Home -> Placelist->Filter->PlaceList->Filter its a never ending loop when all I want is Home -> Placelist -> Filter but data can be pushed backwards. Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to understand can you please post some screen shots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to POP your view but i assume you want to get filtered value into first view,
so you have options like

KVO

Delegates

I Strongly suggest using delegates, if you need a starting point,
look at this url [dismissModalViewController AND pass data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of pushing view controller, you need to go for pop option, once you do the pop, viewWillAppear of PlaceList will be called, s you are using tableview, you can fetch and reload data there. There is no point in pushing again and again without popping.

Answer (score 0):

After Home -> Placelist->Filter , in Filter instead of pushing view just use following

```
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will remove Filter view from stack and your Placelist will be visible.....