# iOS presentingViewController gives No visible @interface error

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Im just learning following beginner tutorial book , i have this code :

```
- (void) presentImagePickerUsingCamera:(BOOL)useCamera
{
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [UIImagePickerController new];
    cameraUI.sourceType = (useCamera? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera:
                                      UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary);

    cameraUI.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
    cameraUI.delegate = self;
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
    [self presentingViewController:cameraUI];
}
```

and this is the interface :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyWhatsit.h"

    @interface MSDetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate,
                                                           UIActionSheetDelegate,
                                                           UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                           UINavigationControllerDelegate>


    @property (strong,nonatomic) MyWhatsit* detailItem;
    @property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
    @property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *locationField;
    @property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    - (IBAction)changeDetail:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender;
    - (void) presentImagePickerUsingCamera:(BOOL)useCamera;
    @end
```

gives me the error:

```
code/MSDetailViewController.m:89:11: No visible @interface for 'MSDetailViewController' declares the selector 'presentingViewController:'
```

i did try to find answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560636/want-to-call-a-method-in-the-presentingviewcontroller-after-user-has-clicked-don)

but nothing help , what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the line:

```
[self presentingViewController:cameraUI];
```

There is no such method.
You are trying to set the controller that presented your view controller. It has no setter since it is readonly (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController)

And if you wanted to set its value, @property gives you this (with set before the variable's name) `[self setSomeInstanceVariable: @"Something"];` as a setter.
So, for example:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *foo;
```

gives you

```
[self foo]; //getter
[self setFoo:@"bar"]; // setter
```

If you want to present a view controller, then you should use the method:

```
presentViewControllerAnimated:completion
```

Comment: theere is no such method : presentViewControllerAnimated

Comment: But it should, that is the standard method to transition between view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

To present something the method is:

`- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`

So in your case:

```
[self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: gives the same error , i can't even left click + command the method
gives me "symbol not found"