# iOS Master-Detail How to load a new view when the add Item button is tapped?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

How do I display a new data entry view when the + button is tapped in a Master-Detail app?
How would the newly displayed view return 2 strings back to the Master-Detail?

The main view has a UITableView

Each cell holds 2 strings.
Main text and a subtitle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not clear, but let me try

first push/modal your new view.

and then use delegate to pass data back.

use below link for delegate tutorial.

[dismissModalViewController AND pass data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)

Comment: I am using Storyboards. Is the tutorial the same?