# How to pass a value to parent view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dismissModalViewController AND pass data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)

I'm new to ios development and stuck on this problem:

I'm using storyboarding and have a navigation controller, `vcA`, with a `TableView` in it which shows some data from a `MutableArray` (which is initialized in `viewdidload` of the same class). After selecting any cell, a second view controller, `vcB`, is shown with a `TextField` in it and a button called "Add to list".

What I want is that when I enter some text in the `TextField` and press the "Add to list" button the text should be added to the array of previous view (which gets shown in the `TableView`) and when i tap the "Back" button on `vcB`'s navigation bar, `vcA` should show the updated `TableView` with the new entry in it (on the top of list). Basically I want to add the text from `vcB`'s `TextField` to the array of `vcA` and show the new array after clicking the BACK button.

I have searched a lot about this issue and seem to find that delegate and protocols is the way to achieve the desired result but I'm having trouble understanding delegation.

Comment: [What Have you Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: This has been asked and answered too many times to count. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6204427/1271826

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the second view controller presenting itself as modal in this example:

In the second view controllers h file:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(id)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item;
@end

@interface SecondPageViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
{
     NSString *previouslyTypedInformation;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *previouslyTypedInformation;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In the second view controllers m file make sure to synthesize properties and add then add this:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
     NSString *itemToPassBack = self.textView.text;
     NSLog(@"returning: %@",itemToPassBack);
     [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];
     //dismiss modal view controller here
}
```

Then in the first view controllers h file set it as delegate:

```
 @interface FirstPageViewController: UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
 @property (nonatomic) NSString *returnedItem;
```

Then in the first view controller's m file synthesize and add the method:

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(SecondPageViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:    (NSString *)item
{
    //using delegate method, get data back from second page view controller and set it to property declared in here
    NSLog(@"This was returned from secondPageViewController: %@",item);
    self.returnedItem=item;

    //add item to array here and call reload
}
```

Now you have the text of what was returned! You can add the string to your array in the first view controller's viewDidLoad and call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and it should work.

Comment: Just an addition, where you initialize your second view controller in your first one, do: 

secondView.myDelegate = self;

Comment: gg13, thank you! The question for your answer should be called "How to easily create delegates". I was felt confused about it, and now not even searching for it, I understand them.

Comment: itemToPassBack is working but when i try it to pass to FirstPageViewController ,it does not moving to FirstPageViewController