# Assigning a variable during [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Tags: ios, segue, poptoviewcontroller

I am looking for a way to assign ivar when `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` is called, similarly to how you can set values when a segue is called:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"login"]) {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    HomeController * home = (HomeController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    home.personHome = self.person;

}
```

where I am assigning an objects variables. The current architecture uses `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

When the application loads the HomeController is the first view but in its view did Load methods it calls `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];` to go to the login screen. Successfully login in pops back.

Advice and direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use delegate methods to set the parameter when the login is successful

Comment: @suhit could you give me an example please?

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106176/how-to-pass-a-value-to-parent-view-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
HomeController *myController = (HomeController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
myController.personHome =self.person ;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work in Swift 2.2:

```
let myController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as! HomeController
myController.personHome = self.person
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```