# How can I use text from a table view cell and display it as a label in a parent view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to figure out the best way for me to use the text from a UITableViewCell to set/change a UILabel in it's parent view. And I'd like it to be done when the user taps on a row. For more clarity, here is a simplified physical representation:

From this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9ipE.png

To this, when the user taps on the row:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmeIb.png

I was thinking I probably just need to use delegates & protocols but then how would I actually change the UILabel? Wouldn't that just pass the text back, instead of passing it back and changing the UILabel? Also, I don't know very much about unwind segues, but could I use one of those to do this instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a value to parent view controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106176/how-to-pass-a-value-to-parent-view-controller)

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106176/how-to-pass-a-value-to-parent-view-controller) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would use a delegate method to pass the data back to the parent. Since you are using some kind of array datasource to populate the table, you already have access to those values in a clean format (instead of pulling from the tableViewCell's hierarchy).

From your table vc:

```
@protocol MyTableViewDelegate
-(void)didSelectText:(NSString *)text;
@end
```

then implement the `-didSelectText:` in your parent VC.

When the user selects the cell, you will have the indexPath, which gives you a section and row.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // It's good practice to do this check first
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectText:)]){
          //basically pull the value out of your data source and send it to the delegate
        [self.delegate didSelectText: self.arrayDataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, nevermind I was just confused with the concept of delegates/protocols in general. I wasn't even thinking about how the main view controller will automatically call the protocol method. Careless mistake. Thanks though!