# iOS: Passing Data wrong

Tags: ios, uilabel, ibaction

This method not working to me. I'm working for minutes. I somehow could not.

This is my code.

```
- (IBAction)donebutton:(id)sender {
    AddTaskViewController *addtask = [[AddTaskViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddTask" bundle:nil];
    addtask.testlabel.text = self.zaman1.text;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Everything is normal but not working. Is that not so? It is wrong?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? At the minute you're creating a view controller then doing absolutely nothing with it. Did you mean to `presentViewController:...`?

Comment: I want to be equal to the label.text

Comment: @Salieh: Tommy is right may be you are confusing it with `presentViewController`. What exactly you are trying to achieve, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I have two label. Label1 in ViewController1 and Label2 in ViewController2. I want to Button click then label2.text = label1.text. It's that simple. But I could not.

Answer (score 1):

You must assign this string in your `viewWillAppear` method, IBOutlets (I'm assuming `testlabel` is a IBOutlet UILabel *) cannot be configured until the view is initialized. If this doesn't help please specify what the error is.

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testlabel; testlabel is weak and nonatomic. And not working. What should I do? I do not understand

Comment: Or, at the very least in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: How do I do this? How can I add into the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @Salieh -- "How do I do this? How can I add into the viewDidLoad" -- Read a book on iOS programming and study the docs for UIViewController and UIViewControllerDelegate.

Comment: Try what @aaron says, if not, make sure all of your connections are properly set.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to create an `NSString*` property on `AddTaskViewController`. You can do it like this:

In `AddTaskViewController.h` add the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* myLabelsText;
```

then in `AddTaskViewController.m` be sure to add this in `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.testlabel.text = self.myLabelsText;
```

Now assuming you've declared your `testLabel` and `myLabelsText` appropriately and they get synthesized, your view controller will apply the string correctly at the proper time and your function should then be changed to this:

```
- (IBAction)donebutton:(id)sender {
    AddTaskViewController *addtask = [[AddTaskViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddTask" bundle:nil];

    // Set the value on your new NSString* property and let the view controller handle the rest
    addTask.myLabelsText = self.zaman1.text;

    // Don't you want to 'present' the view controller rather than 'dismiss' after having provided it with data?
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegate protocols and instead of setting properties of button on previous view controller just pass a string back. This question should help you in implementing Delegate protocol

[dismissModalViewController AND pass data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back?rq=1)