# How do I forward data to a protocol before dismissing a view manually?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, viewcontroller, dismiss

I want to dismiss a view controller manually using `dismissViewController:animated`. The problem is I want to save a value before I dismiss the view, otherwise it becomes `null` and I get no data in my first view. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it

Here is another stackoverflow link :

[dismissModalViewController AND pass data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)