# Protocol method does not get invoked, shows delegate 'nil'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, protocols

I'm working on an iPad App and i'm having issue with delegate... the protocol method does not get invoked. i'm not sure what i'm missing, here is my code.

```
@protocol pickerLabelProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)selectedPickerData:(UILabel *)sender;
@end

@interface showPickerVC : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <pickerLabelProtocol> delegate;
@end

@implementation showPickerVC
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
//i used breakpoint, the 'delegate' is always nil for some reason?
    [self.delegate selectedPickerData:self.mainLabel];
}

----------------------
@interface someViewController : UIViewController <pickerLabelProtocol>
@property (nonatomic, strong) showPickerVC *showPicker;
@end

@implementation someViewController

- (void)selectedPickerData:(UILabel *)sender
{
//protocol method
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.showPicker = [[showPickerVC alloc]init];
    self.showPicker.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: exactly what you want to do? what you want to access?

Comment: "ShowPickerVC" is a popOver, that comes up from "someViewController"... "ShowPickerVC" has a picker, user selects data in picker and i want the selected data to be passed to "someViewController"...

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this code works fine in iPhone but not with iPad probably because of popOver??

Comment: Where is the code that presents showPickerVC?

Comment: showPickerVC is presented through popOver Segue... that works fine, the issue is that in "viewWillDisappear" the delegate shows nil...

Answer (score 1):

I can not got any mistake From your code but i suggest you that Be clear about when you create object of `showPickerVC` add it's `delegate` **self**

Such Like ,

```
showPickerVC *obj = [[showPickerVC alloc] init];
obj.delegate = self; /// YOur protocol delegate 
.
.
[self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

And Also add code as following

```
@implementation showPickerVC

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedPickerData:)])
    {
       [self.delegate selectedPickerData:self.mainLabel];
    }

}
```

For More information about [How to create/use of Protocol.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... the problem is that "delegate" always shows nil, which is why it doesnt invoke the method... is it something to do with popOver? this code works fine with iphone...