# how to send data back with dismissViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, popviewcontroller

i have 2 views in iPhone application. `FirstViewController` and `MultiSelectViewController`.

in `FirstViewController` there is a button to go to `MultiSelectViewController`. In `MultiSelectViewController` i have a `tableviewcontroller` to multiselect and send result back to `FirstViewController` with Done button

my problem is with done button. i don't know how to send data back to the `FirstViewController`. it has to be with `dissmissviewcontroller`.

this is .h file of `MultiSelectViewController`

```
@protocol MultiSelectDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) multiselectViewControllerDismissed;
@end

@interface MultiSelectViewController : UITableViewController
{
  __weak id myDelegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *myData;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *selectedData;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MultiSelectDelegate> myDelegate;
```

this is my done button in .m file of `MultiSelectViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
selectedData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(multiselectViewControllerDismissed)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;

 }
```

and lastly here is my done button action:

```
-(void)multiselectViewControllerDismissed
{
   NSLog(@"%@",selectedData);

}
```

i don't understand how can i send data and get back in `FirstViewController`

Comment: what value you need to pass?

Comment: Try this May be helpfull 

[dismissModalViewController AND pass data back][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back

Thanks & Cheers .

Comment: selectedData, it is an array i fill it in tableview delegates if cell selected

Comment: Please go through the steps described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6204427/3432566

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redefine
`multiselectViewControllerDismissed` delegate method as

```
 multiselectViewControllerDismissedWithData:(NSMutableArray *)dataSelected
```

And, in .h file of `FirstViewController` implement the delegate i.e.,

```
@interface FirstViewController: UIViewController <MultiSelectDelegate>
```

and in the button action of `FirstViewController.m` assign delegate of MultipleSelectViewController as self. ie.,

```
 MultipleSelectViewController * msvc = [[MultipleSelectViewController alloc] init]; 
msvc.myDelegate = self;
```

and implement

```
 -(void)multiselectViewControllerDismissedWithData:(NSMutableArray *)dataSelected
```

this method in `FirstViewController.m`

And, in the Done button action method of `MultipleSelectViewController.m`, call method `multiselectViewControllerDismissedWithData` with delegate i.e.,

```
 [self.myDelegate multiselectViewControllerDismissedWithData:selectedData];
```

That's it.
 You could now pass `selectedData` array from `MultipleSelectViewController` to `FirstViewController`

Comment: thanks for the answer. i changed the done button's action        -(void)done
{
    if([self.myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(multiselectViewControllerDismissed:)])
    {
        [self.myDelegate multiselectViewControllerDismissed:selectedData];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   // NSLog(@"%@",selectedData);
    
} however i can send data back to the FirstViewController i cannot dismiss page. I mean it stay in MultiSelectViewController

Answer (score 0):

Two standard ways of passing data in obj-c:

1. Use references and assign manually. In your example, the first view controller passes a reference of itself to the second view controller. The second view controller assigns a designated property with the required data using the reference.
2. The publisher-subscriber pattern using `LocalNotifications`. The first view controller listens for a particular location notification, and the second view controller, before being dismissed, does a broadcast with the data.

I'd recommend the 1st approach for your example. Some sample code:

In the .h file:

```
@interface FirstViewController:UIViewController

@property NSMutableArray *receivedData; //property to receive selected data

@end
```

In the .m file:

```
MultiSelectViewController *msvc = [MultiSelectViewController alloc] init];
msvc.presentingViewController = self; // pass reference of 1st VC to 2nd VC
[self presentViewController:msvc animated:YES];
```

In MultiSelectViewController.h file:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface MultiSelectViewController: UITableViewController
...

@property FirstViewController *presentingViewController;
...
@end
```

In MultiSelectViewController.m file:

```
-(void)multiselectViewControllerDismissed
{
   NSLog(@"%@",selectedData);
   presentingViewController.receivedData = selectedData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first create your delegate method as

```
-(void)dismiss:(NSString *)str;
```

while did select get a value from based on indexpath.row
and store it as nsstring.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


   self.valueString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrayValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);

   }
```

done button click:

call your delegate method like

```
[self. myDelegate dismiss:"your string which you get from table"]
 [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and in your first view controller…

import the view controller class and call delegate method..

create instance for second view controller...

```
 MultiSelectViewController *txtNext=[[MultiSelectViewController alloc]init];
  txtNext. myDelegate =self;
```

then

```
-(void)dismiss:(NSString *)str
{

NSString *strng=str;
nslog("%@",strng);
}
```