# Objective C - Detect the instance of the previous modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm using the standard code for present & dismiss modal segue

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I want to perform some method of the previous view, in the completion area of the current view.

for ex. the previous view is a menu with profile pic and more stuff, and the current view is view for changing the profile pic. when I dismiss the current view I want to update the `UIImageView` of the profile at the menu view (the previous view).

Is it possible to get the instance of the previous view ?

Comment: See "Passing Data Back" section of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/1271826).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual thing is for your second view controller to define a protocol and a delegate that adopts that protocol, and for your first view controller to make itself the second view controller's delegate. Now the second view controller has a reference to the first (because it is its delegate) and is guaranteed of a method or methods that it can call to hand information back to the first (because the delegate has adopted a protocol).

The question then arises of *when* the first view controller will set itself as the second view controller's delegate. There are two situations:

- The first view controller creates the second view controller in code. Obviously it now has a reference to second view controller and can set itself as its delegate.
- You're using a storyboard and this is a modal presentation segue. In that case, implement `prepareForSegue` in the first view controller. Now you can get the segue's `destinationViewController` - that's the second view controller, so the first view controller can now set itself as the second view controller's delegate.

Comment: For an example, see the end of this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller

Comment: How do I need to initialize delegate?
I mean - I know how to set delegates etc.. but in the second view  I need to write 'previousViewInstance.delegate = self' but how can I get the previousViewInstance? (sorry if I'm not so clear :)

Comment: This answer helped me a bunch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back

Comment: btw Matt, are you THE matt neuberg? if so, thanks for literally the best programming books on the planet :)

Comment: @NewEngland Thanks, the check is in the mail! :)

Comment: @AsiGivati I'll expand my answer a little to answer that.

Comment: @matt have you made other vids like this? www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIufcKpDIRo I found this one amazingly useful!