# Passing Image from popoverview to viewcontroller - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uipopovercontroller

Can I pass an Image from a popoverview to the controller that brings the popoverview forward? Can I pass the image with a delegate or do  I have to put it in NSData to transport it?

I am having struggles with it, I already tried a thousand tutorials but I can't get it working, so my question is:

Is it possible to pass images from popoverviews to viewcontrollers?

And, if yes: what is the easiest way to understand and do this?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back). This may help. Ideally [-popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:) is the best approach to use.

Comment: In that answer, they use strings, and I know that this is possible, but is this also possible with Images, for example an image drawn in the popoverview ( a signature) @vivekmolkar

Comment: I don't see any problem. You can use UIImage as a property instead of NSString. It should work.