# Why doesn't delegate work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have been studying delegate.

so i write code that delegate then run this code.

Can you tell me what's the problem?

this is my code.

ViewController2.h

```
@protocol ViewController2Delegate <NSObject>;
@required
-(void)practiceDelegateMethod:(Float32)var1 andVar2:(Float32)var2;
@end
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <CompressSetupViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

ViewController2.m

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)compressSetupCancleAction:(id)sender {
   [self.delegate practiceDelegateMethod:var1 andVar2:var2];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

ViewController1.h

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController< ViewController2Delegate >
```

ViewController1.m

```
-(void) practiceDelegateMethod:(Float32)var1 andVar2:(Float32)var2{
    NSLog(@"delegate var1 : %@    var2 : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",var1],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",var2]);
}
```

Comment: on ViewController1, did you set ViewController2.delegate = self; ?

Comment: @CongTran yes, set in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @CongTran  ViewController2Delegate* vc2 = [[ViewController2Delegate alloc]init];
    vc2.delegate = self;

Comment: Creating a view controller like that doesn't look right.

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting  the reference of viewController2 in viewController1 , and then calling <ref of ViewController 2>.delegate = self ?. I think you have reference of viewController 2 in viewcontroller1 as nil.

Comment: @LearneriOS i write <ViewController2>.delegate = self in viewDidLoad.

Comment: no... <ViewController2> by this I mean this is a placeholder for your reference for example if you ref name is abc it would be abc.delegate = self .  Please make sure that abc should not be nil.

Comment: Sometimes you should think before copying & pasting codes. The answers mentioned below are right. You have to change delegate name

Comment: @LearneriOS thanks your help. i'm solved problem use notification.

Comment: @PrinceAgrawal  thanks your help. i'm solved problem use notification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is one other way to pass data between viewcontrollers `NSNotification`

From the class sending the message, post a notification like :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME" object: anyobjectyouwanttosendalong(can be nil)];
```

In the view controllers where you want to be notified of the notification when posted:

In the viewDidLoad do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(METHOD_YOU_WANT_TO_INVOKE_ON_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED) name:@"YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME" object:sameasbefore/nil];
```

Important! Don't forget this in your viewDidUnload():

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME" object:sameasbefore/nil];
```

Note:-When it's only one object notifying another one, you're better off using protocols :) But in this case since there are multiple view controllers listening, use notifications

if you want to go with protocol then refer above link

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)

Comment: thanks your help. i'm solved problem use notification.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10725738)

Comment: @JisooKwon i edited my answer if its rights then give it right mark so its help for other :)

Comment: and @NeilMasson Thanks for your advise :)

Answer (score -1):

In your HomeViewController When ever you make instance of `ViewController2` assign delegate self

```
    ViewController2 *controller = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
    controller.delegate = self
```

Comment: It is not necesary that the user would have to create a new reference... they can get it fromm somewhere else as well...

Comment: yes it is not necessary to create a new reference but this was just for understanding purpose

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you are not getting the reference of the viewController2 in viewController1 due to some problem. 
get the non-nil reference of viewController2 in viewcontroller1 and then

`<ref of ViewController 2>.delegate = self`

I think you have reference of viewController 2 in viewcontroller1 as nil.

Answer (score -1):

Try after replacing

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <CompressSetupViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

with:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <ViewController2Delegate> delegate;
```

Comment: original code is CompressSetupViewControllerDelegate.

Comment: Have you set classObj.delegate = self; in  ViewController1 after creating object of class?

Comment: Then where is your code for CompressSetupViewControllerDelegate protocol?

Comment: Hi your question is little bit confusing: because you say that original code is CompressSetupViewControllerDelegate and there is no code for CompressSetupViewControllerDelegate protocol and in ViewController1.h file you write <ViewController2Delegate>. Basically you want to work with ViewController2Delegate or CompressSetupViewControllerDelegate?

Comment: thanks your help. i'm solved problem use notification.