# Swift 2.2 : Pass value between view controllers iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to **pass value between two view controller but it failed.**
Second view controller (which is table view controller) is presented **modally** when button present in first view controller is pressed.

When user taps on any cell present in second view controller it is dismissed and value of cell is set to button present in first view controller.

Below is code that I've used :

**ForgotPasswordViewController**

```
class ForgotPasswordViewController: UIViewController {

    var securityQuestion = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var btnSecurityQuestion: UIButton!

    //MARK: - viewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    var secQuestionAccessor: (String) {
        get{
            return securityQuestion
        }set(param) { print("param : \(param)") //Value is correctly printed in console
           securityQuestion = param
            print("securityQuestion : \(securityQuestion)")  //Value is correctly printed in console
        }
    }

    //MARK: - viewWillAppear
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {        
        . . .

        print("secQuestionAccessor : \(secQuestionAccessor)") //Value is empty here

        if secQuestionAccessor == "" {
            btnSecurityQuestion.setTitle("Select", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        else {
            btnSecurityQuestion.setTitle(secQuestionAccessor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        . . .
    }
  . . .
}
```

**SecurityQuestionViewController :**

```
class SecurityQuestionViewController: UITableViewController {
  . . .

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let objForgotPassword = ForgotPasswordViewController()
        print("\(responseQuestion.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String)") //Value printed correctly here
        objForgotPassword.secQuestionAccessor = responseQuestion.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
  . . .
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

Where I'm going wrong?  Any other solution?

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33229483/1753005) helped in **creating a delegate using Swift language.**
However, the `app crashes when second view controller is presented using modal segue.`

It **crashes when delegate is declared weak and set to nil in second view controller.** It works fine for show segue.

How can this be done using modal segue?

Comment: `objForgotPassword` is completely new instance, it is not previous view controller, and it will never be presented on screen

Comment: @ShadowOf is right. Plus, you can take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back as suggested by Max Pevsner.

Comment: You can access instance of ForgotPasswordViewController by checking self.presentingViewController in SecurityQuestionViewController

Comment: @JJBoursier : Pls check question. It is further elaborated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a protocol to your `SecurityQuestionViewController` with a function that accepts the data you want to pass to the previous viewController as a parameter. In your `ForgotPasswordViewController` implement that function. Before dismissing the `SecurityQuestionViewController` call that function on delegate.

Comment: Question is further elaborated. Pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Bro I Can give you clue... No need of notification no need of protocol...

**Do one thing Just grab the parent view controller's instance from navigation hierarchy and access its property variable in which you want to set the data**

If you are presenting View controller then access parent by this

```
ParentVC *objParentVC = self.presentingViewController
```

If you are pushing view controller then access parent by

```
ParentVC *objParentVC = [[self.navigationController childViewController] objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.childViewController.count - 2];
```

Just for clarification.
Here if you -2 will be your parent. -1 will be your current view controller. as its count