# Done button in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I want to make static table view to pass data into coredata to add new item to my TableView, but i dont know how to connect "Done" button to make action, from another view controller (UIView).

I got this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZDxU.png)

I wanted to make it i one ViewController, but when i'm switching my Table View to static cells i got problem solved by this: [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC-CMtle8hk)

So, now i got AddItemTableViewController class, and i want to run this code on my "Done" button, but i don't know how to connect that button from another view.

```
import UIKit

class AddItemTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let task = ItemsList(context: context)
        task.title = titleTextField.text!

        // Save the data to coredata
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

        let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Could you please advice, how to deal with it? thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use `delegate` approach. Just declare a protocol in `AddItemTableViewController` and a `delegate` property, set it in your ViewController and implement protocol's method in it

Comment: Delegate approach is one way, using blocks can be easier in some cases: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19867352/985027